# How to write a pep8 configuration (pep8.rc) file?

Tags: python, pep8, pep

I found the documentation for pep8 but wasn't able to understand how to write these. I couldn't even find any examples with options other than setting max-line-length and ignore.

I am trying to write a `.pep8.rc` file in which, among other things, I need to do the following:

- enable show source
- enable statistics
- enable count
- exclude a directory (say, for example `./random`)

Can somebody answer with an example or link to one?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The preferred way is to use a `setup.cfg` in the top-level of the project (.cfg has the same syntax as a [.ini file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#supported-ini-file-structure)), which should contain a `[pep8]` section. For example:

```
[pep8]
ignore = E226,E302,E41
max-line-length = 160
```

*Note: the error codes are defined in the [pep8 docs](http://pep8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html#error-codes).*

---

- autopep8 find this same `[pep8]` section as pep8.
- flake8 needs a [`[flake8]` section](http://flake8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html) in setup.cfg.
- yapf looks for a [`[yapf]` section](https://github.com/google/yapf#formatting-style) in setup.cfg.

Comment: Does **NOT** work with pytest! What does, is `pep8maxlinelength` ([source](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-pep8/))

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, the answer from Andy Hayden does not work for `pytest` / `pytest-pep8` / `flake8`.

### pytest-pep8

For that, you have to use either

```
# content of setup.cfg
[pytest]
pep8maxlinelength = 99
```

or

```
[pytest]
max-line-length=99
```

Strangely, **the following does not work**

```
[tool:pytest]
max-line-length=99
```

### pytest-flake8

Add

```
 [flake8]
 max-line-length=99
```

Answer (score 2):

They renamed pep8 to [pycodestyle](https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle) to avoid confusion.

You can create a setup.cfg file with:

```
[pycodestyle]
ignore = E226,E302,E41
max-line-length = 119
exclude =
    tests/
    docs/
```

For the error codes, you can read [this](https://readthedocs.org/projects/pycodestyle/downloads/pdf/stable/) documentation.